# Reading errors from multiple channels

Tags: go

Like many go programmers, have so far avoided doing anything significant with channels so this apparently simple scenario has got me stumped!

I want multiple goroutines to send results checked by a single parent. If any send an error, the parent should signal for them all to stop. The parent should read the results non-sequentially.

This code works provided one of the goroutines does send an error i.e. if you comment in the `11` inside nums otherwise we just get stuck in the for loop forever.

```golang
func main() {
    type Result struct {
        Error    error
        Response int
    }
    checkStatus := func(done <-chan interface{}, ns []int) <-chan Result {
        results := make(chan Result)
        go func() {
            defer close(results)
            for _, n := range ns {
                result := Result{Response: n}
                if n == 11 {
                    result.Error = fmt.Errorf("problem...\n")
                }
                select {
                case <-done:
                    return
                case results <- result:
                }
            }
        }()
        return results
    }

    done := make(chan interface{})
    defer close(done)

    nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 /*11,*/, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    c1 := checkStatus(done, nums[:5])
    c2 := checkStatus(done, nums[5:])
    for {
        var r Result
        select {
        case r = <-c1:
            if r.Error != nil {
                fmt.Printf("error1: %v", r.Error)
                return
            }
            fmt.Printf("Response1: %v\n", r.Response)
        case r = <-c2:
            if r.Error != nil {
                fmt.Printf("error2: %v", r.Error)
                return
            }
            fmt.Printf("Response2: %v\n", r.Response)
        }
    }
}
```

The only way I can see to fix it is the change the `for` loop so it reads from `c1` and `c2` but I can't see a way to do this non-sequentially?

https://go.dev/play/p/7dRPMDn1Za2

Comment: `if you comment in the 11 inside nums otherwise we just get stuck in the for loop forever.` unless i missread, it returns.

Comment: w/t spoiling a solution, you are looking for smthg like this, i guess, https://go.dev/play/p/8P7kzRZ3I8w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading from closed channels and they always return a zero value. What you can do is to turn off a select case by using a comma ok idiom while reading from a channel and then assign the channel to nil. If the other one is nil as well then return.

`case` with a nil channel never runs.

Just by extending your code (similarly for the case with `c2`):

```
case r, ok := <-c1:
    if !ok {
        c1 = nil
        if c2 == nil {
            return
        }
        continue
    }
    if r.Error != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error1: %v", r.Error)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Response1: %v\n", r.Response)
```

But I'd rather try to refactor the whole implementation.

What you can consider is using `sync.WaitGroup` from the `sync` pkg or `errgroup.Group` from the `errgroup` pkg.